# Xamarin using .NETStandard 1.6

Tags: xamarin, .net-standard

How can I use .NETStandard libraries on a Xamarin project. I have already made a try to create a portable library targeting .NETStandard 1.6.
this is the project.json of portable library
[image]

This is the properties of portable library
[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced a similar problem and was able to solve it by recreating the .net standard library as outlined here in [Orens Blog](https://oren.codes/2017/04/23/using-xamarin-forms-with-net-standard-vs-2017-edition/).

He even has a sample on github which is a great starting point.